# Controlling the visibility of a FeatureGroup in Folium with an HTML checkbox

Tags: python, leaflet, html, django, folium

I'm working on a project in Django where I want to show layers on a map by checking or unchecking boxes which I created using bootstrap. I am aware it is possible to use `LayerControl` to get these boxes, but I would like to use the boxes I created. Is this possible in `folium`?

This is my views.py in Django.

```
def third_view(request):

    m = folium.Map(width='100%', height='90%', crs='Simple', tiles=None)
    base_map = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Basemap', overlay=True)

    image= 'static/images/stitched_map.png'
    bounds=[[0, 0], [750, 750]]

    overlay = folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(image, bounds).add_to(base_map)
    base_map.add_to(m)

    html = 'Here lies Balin, son of Fundin'

    iframe = folium.IFrame(html)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe,
                         min_width=200,
                         max_width=200)

    layer1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='layer1', overlay=False)
    folium.Marker([350, 350], icon=icon_circle, tooltip='TA 1267', popup=popup).add_to(layer1)
    layer1.add_to(m)

    m.fit_bounds(bounds)

    m = m._repr_html_()

    context = {
        'map': m,
    }

    return render(request, 'third.html', context)
```

This is my html page/checkbox which I want to link it to:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      {{ map|safe }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <h3><span style="color: #e8c4b4;">Places</span></h3>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Cities</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Points of Interest</label>
      </div>
      <h3><span style="color: #e8c4b4;">Travels</span></h3>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Frodo</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the output webpage that is not working:

[image]